# How to make 2 "Friends" compare and see if they are on eachothers list of friends?

Tags: python, list, class, default

So I am using classes and def to make it so if 2 People (Which I have as a class) are in each others friends list, well their ID which is specific to each person. Be removed from that list, and be added to a mutual friends lists.

I haven't tried much, I am stuck on comparing those 2 lists.

```
class People:

    '''People to make friendships, have a name, and a unique ID'''

    numsTimes = 0           ###Class variable for ID

    def __init__(self, name="anon"):
        if name == "anon": self.myname = makeRName()   ####Random Name
        else: self.myname = name
        self.friends = [] 
        self.mutualf = [] 

        self.ID = People.numsTimes          ###Unique ID
        People.numsTimes += 1

    def addFriend(self):            ###Ability for people to add others as friends
        self.friends.append(People.ID)

    def addMutual(self):
        ################I am looking for some if statement here.
        ###############Somehow remove others ID from both lists        
        self.mutualf.append(People.ID)
        else: return
```

I hope that it will check eachothers friends list, if they are friends with eachother, they will be added to eachothers mutual list and removed from friends list.

Comment: i don't see you passing the others ID in `addMutual`

Comment: yes, I am kind of stuck. I am randomly making people, so I am having trouble thinking on how to compare 2 lists of people in which don't exist ha ha.

Comment: Simply put, you would need two id's and two friends list to achieve what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would use sets instead of lists for friends.
You could compare mutual friends with:

```
class People:

    '''People to make friendships, have a name, and a unique ID'''

    numsTimes = 0           ###Class variable for ID

    def __init__(self, name="anon"):
        if name == "anon": self.myname = makeRName()   ####Random Name
        else: self.myname = name
        self.friends = {}
        self.mutualf = {} 

        self.ID = People.numsTimes          ###Unique ID
        People.numsTimes += 1

    def addMutual(self,other):
        mutual = self.friends.intersection(other.friends)
        self.mutual.add(mutual)
        self.friends.remove(mutual)
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you. I am new to python so I did not even know about .intersection. Thanks so much!